# How use a MainApp method in container class StartPage? Just in case someone needs it

Tags: tkinter

How use a MainApp method in container class StartPage? Just in case someone needs it.

This is how to get a method from class App and use in class StartPage.
I did this to help someone with the same problem.
It took me time to find out.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=12, columnspan=6, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(LoginPage)

    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()


    # HOW TO GET THIS FUNCTION IN class  StartPage? Answer bellow.
    def open_file(self):  # controller here is parent  MainApp(tk.Tk)
        filename = askopenfilename(initialdir="C:/000_tmp/",
                                         filetypes=(("eeg file", "*.edf"),
                                                    ("eeg file", "*.EDF"),
                                                    ('eeg file', '*.fif'),
                                                    ("all files", "*.*")),
                                         title="Choose a file.")





class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        #THE ANSWER IS:
        open_file_if_nonexistent = MainApp.open_file(self.controller)  # controller is  App
        if EEG_raw == '':
            open_file_if_nonexistent




class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
```

I hope it can help someone.
best regards
PKanda

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Your code does not work because `open_file()` does not return `filename`.  Also `self.controller.open_file()` is used normally instead of `MainApp.open_file(self.controller)`.

Comment: My real code is very long, here it is incomplete, the subject is 'only' how to get the function from mainApp in Start page. 
I´m just happy to share something that worked to me,  just an insight. By the way, thank you for sharing your expertise, I will try it.
best regards

Comment: Dear Mr acw1668,

MainApp.open_file(self.controller) and self.controller.open_file() = both work to me
but your code is more clear and concise. I've learned something important to my project thanks to you !

best